# Datetime representation in python

Tags: python, dictionary, datetime

I have a file containing some timestamps. I want to display the event frequency/hour, without zero padding. I have:

```
dictionary = {}
for line in my_list:
    line = line.strip()
    time = datetime.datetime.strptime(line, "%A, %d %B %Y, %I:%M %p").strftime("%H")
    if time in dictionary:
        dictionary[time] += 1
    else:
        dictionary[time] = 1
sorted_days = sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda dictionary:dictionary[1])
for time in sorted_days:
    print("{0};{1}".format(time[0], time[1]))
```

Presently, the display format is 00;323, 01;21, etc in range of 00 to 23. What I want is the hour without the leading zero: 1;21, 2;352, etc. I tried the strftime("%-H"), which does remove the first 0, but then it causes problems when I want to use sorted() by key, the order goes 0,1,10, etc. I tried the lstrip and replace, no success. How do I remove the 0 padding in such a way that does not interfere with my attempts to "sort" the dictionary (yes, I know dictionaries can not be sorted, I am referring to the display format only)?

Comment: Don't sort as strings.

Comment: You could use integer hour instead as key. Default string representation would be non zero padded then.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Anyone who encountered similar issues might find my answer useful. There is a number of solutions I tried. One can change the key names:

```
dictionary[new_key] = dictionary.pop(old_key)
```

Mr.Fuppes in the comments provided another viable solution: using int(hour) as key. Also, one could leave the keys alone. The problem that I experienced was due to the fact that once the 0 was removed, the sort could not recognize its time. Solving this would require a new list/array. The dictionary (with padded zero) is sorted, then the value is pushed to a new array, then loop or filter to remove the zero. Any of the above would work and making hours integers is the simplest.